# jquery not updating DOM after $.getJSON in IE/Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, json, dom, cross-browser

I have a page that contains an element, `<displayedimage>`, that is not getting updated using jquery's document.ready/$.getJSON funcitonality in IE 6 and IE 8 (probably IE 7 too even though I haven't tested). This same piece of funcitonality works fine on XP Safari and OS X Safari, OS X Chrome, OS X Opera, etc. So, here's what happens:

I have an element, , that is empty on first load, but gets populated by a javascript method executed by document.ready:

```
<div id="imagecontrol">
   <displayedimage></displayedimage>
</div>
```

gets updated by:

```
function loadFirstImage() {
        $.getJSON("/servlet/access/image/" + id,
            function(json) {
                $("displayedimage").html("<a href=\"/servlet/images/" + json.images[0].filename + "\"><img src=\"/servlet/images/s_" + json.images[0].filename + "\"></img></a>");
                $("imagelabel").html(json.images[0].label);
            });
}
```

As stated, this system works fine in OS X Safari, OS X Chrome, OS X Opera, XP Safari, but doesn't seem to do anything in XP IE. I've performed simple debugging (alert("loadFirstImage called") in the loadFirstImage method and it gives me an alert, so it seems that it might be some .getJSON issue? Any suggestions on where to start with something like this? Thanks.

Comment: I never know that 'displayimage' tag in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using arbitrary DOM element names can give you this kind of problems and inconsistencies.

Why don't you just simply use a standard element, like a `div` or a `span` perhaps?:

```
<div id="imagecontrol">
   <div id="displayedimage"></div>
</div>
```

And in your `$.getJSON` callback you set the contents of it:

```
$("#displayedimage").html(/*...*/);
```

Browsers will accept any markup, even if it's not legal HTML. By this, it means that the browser will try to *guess* about what you *probably* meant. That can lead to having browser compatibility issues as the one you are now, for that I would recommend you to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your markup.

Comment: I assumed that I could create whatever element name I desired in IE. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with sematics

```
<div id="imagecontrol">
   <div id="displayedimage"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$.getJSON("/servlet/access/image/" + id,
  function(json) {
    $("#displayedimage").html("<a href=\"/servlet/images/" + json.images[0].filename + "\"><img src=\"/servlet/images/s_" + json.images[0].filename + "\"></img></a>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using custom tags, have you explicitly created those tags as needed for IE? Put this in the `head` of your page:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.createElement('displayedimage');
  document.createElement('imagelabel');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

**For the record:** I agree with the other answers that you should stick to valid tags or you may run into name collision later on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used standard tags and voila, it worked. Good example on defining custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that **if `$.getJSON` is called multiple times** on the same page (perhaps as a result of button click or similar), **in IE 7/8** your **data will NOT be updated** because IE caches ajax requests by default (e.g. Chrome and FF don't do that).

Solution is to use **`$.ajax`** method instead (**`$.getJSON`** is a wrapper method for **`$.ajax`**):

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'JSON_SOURCE_URL',
      dataType: 'json', 
      cache: false, // 'cache: false' must be present for IE 7 & 8
      success: function(data) {
        // do your thing with 'data'
      }
    });
```